# MongoDB error while installing Rocket.chat in CentOS 8 server with Apache

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache, rocket.chat, centos8

I am following this tutorial to install a Rocket.chat server in CentOS:
https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rocket-chat-server-on-centos-7/

I am new to mongodb and node.js so I am not very familiar with how all this works

At the moment I am looking for something simple that just works

When I reach the step where it says to execute

```
node main.js
```

I get the following error:

```
[username@localhost Rocket.chat]$ node main.js 
/opt/Rocket.chat/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/opt/Rocket.chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:450:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at processMessage (/opt/Rocket.chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/Rocket.chat/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'not master and slaveOk=false',
  code: 13435,
  codeName: 'NotMasterNoSlaveOk',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

The tutorial says I should be able to see the Rocket.chat web interface if I go to https://yourdomain.com:3000 but I get an unable to connect page, which I suppose is due to the error above

The tutorial also says node main.js is to check if MongoDB is running or not. I can see that MongoDb service is running by executing

```
systemctl status mongod
```

so this error seems to be caused by something else.

How do I find out what is causing this error? Or are there any mistakes in this tutorial? I have found other tutorials regarding installing Rocket.chat in CentOS but most of them use nginx as hte web server while I need to use Apache.

Comment: The error says you have mongo running a replica set and you are trying to connect to the secondary member of the replica directly. I fail to see how you managed to do that from the tutorial alone though. Do you reproduce it on a clean system? Do you follow the manual literally or do you adjust anything?

Comment: @AlexBlex I don't actually follow the manual literally, I have already installed MongoDB and node.js using other methods because I needed them to install something else. I am using this particular tutorial only to install Rocket.chat. I have done a few other things different as well, for example if I use the curl command as given the tar command fails, I think whatever it downloads is not an archive file. So I go to https://rocket.chat/releases/latest/download from the browser and download it from there.

Comment: hmmm, what kind of help you expect then. Nobody knows what steps you've taken to set it up. You provided only the guide that you didn't follow and the command that starts unknown version of rocket. The error says you mongo set up doesn't meet app's expectation. You need to either change mongo to standalone or change rocket to connect to replica.

Comment: @AlexBlex when I say i didn't follow the guide, like I said, I meant I didn't install mongodb and node js using the exact command shown there. I don't know much about mongo or node but from the tutorial it looks like it's a standard install, which I think I have done correctly, just from some different tutorials. If you actually go to the rocket chat download link it redirects and auto downloads a specific version (rocketchat3.3.0, I suppose it is the current latest). I just want to know why I'm not getting the rocket chat setup web interface.

Comment: Ah, that's simple - you don't have the web interface because the server (node main.js) failed to connect to mongodb and crashed.

Comment: @AlexBlex I see thank you. And is there anything in that error message that indicates why node.js didn't connect to mongodb? or is it just a general error message?

Comment: It's very precise error message. It tells you that connection settings in node.js are for standalone instance whilst the mongo is running in replicaset mode. These 2 modes are not compatible. It's 3rd time I am rephrasing the same thing and I doubt I can make it any clear =( If it still doesn't ring a bell I'm afraid you need to seek some professional help.